# Save the query result from a table into a variable then send it into another table

Tags: php, sql

I have a table named city where the are city_id and city_name columns there. What I want is that I want to query the value of city_id from the city table into another table named spinner which also contain city_id column there.

Both city_id have same int data type.

Here is my php code sample

```
<?php
$response = array();
include 'DBConnect.php';

//Get the input request parameters
// $inputJSON = file_get_contents('php://input');
// $input = json_decode($inputJSON, TRUE); //convert JSON into array

//Check for Mandatory parameters
 $city_name = $_POST['city_name'];
// $city_id = $_POST['city_id'];
// $city_query = "SELECT city.city_id FROM city INNER JOIN spinner ON city.city_id = spinner.city_id";

// $sql = "SELECT city_id FROM city WHERE $city_name ";
// $stmt = $con->query("SELECT city_id FROM city WHERE $city_name");
// $city_id = $stmt;


    // $insertQuery  = "INSERT INTO spinner(city_id) VALUES (?)";
    $insertQuery = "INSERT INTO spinner(city_id) SELECT city_id FROM city WHERE $city_name";
    if($stmt = $con->prepare($insertQuery)){
        // $stmt->bind_param('s',$city_id);
        $stmt->execute();
        $response["status"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "city data sent";
        $stmt->close();
    }
    else{
        $reponse["message"] = "cannot send data";
    }

echo json_encode($response);
```

?>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The subquery part always be in `()`. And check the WHERE condition according to your need:

```
INSERT INTO spinner(city_id) VALUES((SELECT city_id FROM city WHERE city_name = "$city_name"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You're forgetting to set your values. Your syntax should be something like this

```
INSERT INTO spinner(city_id) VALUES((SELECT city_id FROM city WHERE city_name = '$city_name'))
```

Just a quick comment, I would personally separate my query. I wouldn't nest them